# Reference static method in typescript type: Automatically pick up method signature

Tags: typescript, static

I have a class with a static method:

```js
class Application {
  static get(): string {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now I want to reference this static get method in another class. I know I can do this:

```js
class Caller {
  klass: { get (): typeof Application["get"] }
}
```

This works easily if the method take no arguments. **Edit: Please see below why this is wrong**

Now if I add an argument:

```js
class Application {
  static get(argument: string): string {
    ...
  }
}
```

... I also have to change `Caller` (and every other class having this signature):

```js
class Caller {
  klass: { get (argument: string): typeof Application["get"] }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this? Because it is obvious that `klass.get` always follows the function signature of `Application.get`. Is there a way to tell typescript something like this:

```js
class Caller {
  klass: { get (signatureof typeof Application["get"]): typeof Application["get"] }
}
```

---

**Edit**: Actually I just realized the above is *wrong*: I actually defined `get()` to *return* something that behaves like `typeof Application["get"]`.

I gave it a new shot with this:

```js
class Caller {
  klass: {
    [Key in keyof typeof Application]: typeof Application[Key]
  }
}
```

... though I have yet to see if this solves it, brb.

---

**Edit 2**: Both ways seem to be possible:

```js
// reference all properties
class Caller {
  klass: {
    [Key in keyof typeof Application]: typeof Application[Key]
  }
}

// or if only one specific thing is needed
// reference one property
class Caller {
  klass: {
    get: typeof Application["get"]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately if the references method is more complex, e.g. `get()` accesses static properties defined on `Application`, this get more complicated though, since typescript will then complain about those not being found (if only the method is referenced, not every property).

So I think the way to go is to reference all properties to be on the safe side.

Comment: Why not ` klass: { get: typeof Application["get"] }` `get` is of the same type (in this case same siganture) with `typeof Application["get"]`. Your mapped type solution would also work but would take all members from `Application` which I am not sure you want

Comment: Yeah, this looks good. My class if somewhat more complex though, so I had also to do `klass: { get: ..., new (): Application }` (otherwise I got some errors about `this context being wrong`. Anyway, I think I *want* all members of that class, since it *is* that class.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir please post your comment as an answer, then I'll accept it because it technically answers my question! (picking up all properties was not asked in the first place)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference the type of the static method using `typeof Class['methodName']`. You can use this type directly as the type for `get`:

```
class Caller {
  klass: {
    get: typeof Application["get"]
  }
}
```

This will mean `get` as the same type as the method `get` of  `Application`. `typeof Application["get"]` is the whole function signature of the method, so any changes to parameters or return type will be reflected in the `get` on `klass`

Answer (score 0):

You could define `get`'s type in the same file, like this:

```js
type ApplicationGetType = (arg: string) => string;
```

Then use that in both function definitions, then any changes only have to be done once, to the type definitions.

You could also try `Parameters<Application['get']>` and `ReturnType<Application['get']>` to get the correct types when referencing that method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though though I'd avoid to create extra types if possible. Because my class actually *is* my type definition. Good idea to use `Parameters` and `ReturnType` though.